# Solve non linear equation numpy.

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

**Edit:** **Everything is good :)**

```
 This is a code which works with small values of t=20 and TR=([[30,20,12,23..],[...]]) but when I put higher values it is shown "Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.". Do you know how to solve this problem??  

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.special import erfc
from scipy import  sqrt
from scipy import  exp
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d




# The function to inverse:
t = 100
alfa = 1.1*10**(-7)
k = 0.18
T1 = 20
Tpow = 180

def F(h):
    p = erfc(h*sqrt(alfa*t)/k)
    return T1 + (Tpow-T1)*(1-exp((h**2*alfa*t)/k**2)*(p))

# Interpolation 
h_eval = np.linspace(-80, 500, 200)   # critical step: define the discretization grid
F_inverse = interp1d( F(h_eval), h_eval, kind='cubic', bounds_error=True )


# Some random data:
TR = np.array([[130, 100, 130, 130, 130],
       [ 90, 101, 100, 120,  90],
       [130, 130, 100, 100, 130],
       [120, 101, 120,  90, 110],
       [110, 130, 130, 110, 130]])

# Compute the array h for a given array TR
h = F_inverse(TR)
print(h)

# Graph to verify the interpolation 
plt.plot(h_eval, F(h_eval), '.-', label='discretized F(h)');
plt.plot(h.ravel(), TR.ravel(), 'or', label='interpolated values')
plt.xlabel('h'); plt.ylabel('F(h) or TR'); plt.legend();
```

---

---

Has anyone an idea how to solve non-linear, implicit equation in numpy.
I have array TR and other values which are included in my equation.

I need to solve it - as a result receive a new array with the same shape

Comment: What is `F(h)` doing? What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I have equation:
0=TR+(Tpow-T1)*(1-np.exp(h**2*alfa*t/k**2)+2/(3*np.sqrt(3))*h**3*(alfa*t)**(3/2)/k**3)
where h is my unknown value.
I wanna find solution of that equation. (consider that TR is an array)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using an 1D interpolation to compute the inverse of the `F(h)` function. Because non [standard root finding method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) is used, the error is not controlled, and the discretization grid have to be chosen with care. However, the interpolated inverse function can be directly computed over an array.

note: the definition of `F` is modified, the problem is now `Solve h for F(h) = TR`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# The function to inverse:
t = 10
alfa = 1.1*10**(-7)
k = 0.18
T1 = 20
Tpow = 100

def F(h):
    A = np.exp(h**2*alfa*t/k**2)
    B = h**3*2/(3*np.sqrt(3))*(alfa*t)**(3/2)/k**3
    return -(Tpow-T1)*( 1 - A + B )

# Interpolation 
h_eval = np.linspace(40, 100, 50)   # critical step: define the discretization grid
F_inverse = interp1d( F(h_eval), h_eval, kind='cubic', bounds_error=True )


# Some random data:
TR = np.array([[13, 10, 13, 13, 13],
       [ 9, 11, 10, 12,  9],
       [13, 13, 10, 10, 13],
       [12, 11, 12,  9, 11],
       [11, 13, 13, 11, 13]])

# Compute the array h for a given array TR
h = F_inverse(TR)
print(h)

# Graph to verify the interpolation 
plt.plot(h_eval, F(h_eval), '.-', label='discretized F(h)');
plt.plot(h.ravel(), TR.ravel(), 'or', label='interpolated values')
plt.xlabel('h'); plt.ylabel('F(h) or TR'); plt.legend();
```

With the other function, the following lines are changed:

```
from scipy.special import erf
def F(h):
    return (Tpow-T1)*(1-np.exp((h**2*alfa*t)/k**2)*(1.0-erf(h*np.sqrt(alfa*t)/k)))

# Interpolation 
h_eval = np.linspace(15, 35, 50)   # the range is changed
```

Comment: thanks a lot - it works perfect with that equation but when I try to use `(Tpow-T1)*(1-exp((h**2*alfa*t)/k**2)*(1.0-erf(h*sqrt(alfa*t)/k)))` instead of `-(Tpow-T1)*( 1 - A + B )` an error occurs:
`AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'extract_multiplicatively'`

Comment: I tested the function and it works well: Which `erf` function do you use?, Is it from Scipy?

Comment: I've just updated all code to check - if you could of course :)

Comment: Be careful from which library the mathematical functions are imported: `scipy` and `numpy` work with nd-array, but `sympy` is something different and do not works with nd-array

Comment: Thanks a lot - now everything is ok

Comment: Is it possible to compute that code while T1 is also an array? (with the same shape as TR).
Take variable from TR[1,1] and from T1[1,1] then TR[2,2] and T1[2,2] and so on... compute it by my equation and put in "h" array

Comment: maybe you could reduce the equation to a 1D case, for instance solve `F(h) == TR/(Tpow-T1)` where `TR/(Tpow-T1)` is computed element wise? Performing a 2D interpolation is possible, but it becomes harder to check that the discretization used is correct

Comment: I will try to do it. Really thanks for your help I appreciate it. I also made a new question about problem associated with two arrays maybe sb has an easy solution for it. I'm just a beginner in this kind of stuff. 
Thanks again