# Solve equation with two arrays and show it as a new one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equation, implicit

**edit:**
Proper values and equation:

```
R=(Tpow-T)*(1-exp((x**2*alfa*t)/k**2)*(1.0-erf(x*sqrt(alfa*t)/k)))
R = np.array([[24.7,46.12, 64.78, 81.12, 95.52],
       [ 108,119.6, 183, 183, 183],
       [129.7,138.77, 146.9, 154.3, 161],
       [167.06,172.6,177.7, 182.3, 186]])


T = np.array([[20,20,20,20,20],
       [20,20,20,20],
       [20,31,12,23,14],
       [15,11,37,28,19]])
```

I calculate x in excel but only for T=20, correct values should be around:

```
x = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50],
       [60,70,80,90],
       [100,?,?,?,?],
       [?,?,?,?,?]])
```

---

let's look at random (*implicit*) equation:

```
R[i,j]=T[i,j]*exp(x*B)*x*A
```

where R,T - are 2D np.array, A,B - constant values and x is unknown value.

How to write right loops to get numerical result of that equation in new array.
I would like to solve my equation independently for each:

R[1,1], T[1,1] = x[1,1]

R[2,2], T[2,2] = x[2,2]

and so on.

.

.

It's not so easy because of operating on implicit function

random values:

```
TR = np.array([[24,46, 64, 81, 95],
       [167,172,177, 182, 186]])

T1 = np.array([[22,10,6,52,12],
       [10,10,2,3,6]])

A = 20
B = 30




 X = np.array([[?,?,?,?,?],
              [?,?,?,?,?]])
```

As you suppose I'm beginner in programming so please try to explain to me as a kid.:)

I got help with equation with one array and implicit equation but I cannot implement it to this kind of problem:
[Solve non linear equation numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920645/solve-non-linear-equation-numpy/51921769?noredirect=1#comment90882409_51921769)

Comment: Can you show an example with expected output?

Comment: I'm sorry but don't have any.

Comment: Let me put it this way: can you show how you would solve the problem with maths, with example numbers

Comment: I'm sorry but don't have any but in the link which i put above is proper equation and value of R array(TR). 
The T1 will have value around 20-40
expected x value under 700

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of parameters, alpha, t , k..you should explain what's mean each an example with explicit value.

I don't know if you can do it by using only python, but I think if you have an equation like that:

```
R=beta*T*exp(alpha*X)*X
```

Supposing that alpha and beta are constant, the easy way is to check if T is a reversible matrix then you will get only this equation

```
reverse(T)*R=beta*exp(alpha*X)*X
```

and using this expression you will get a linear equation and then you can use **np.linalg.solve** to solve it

[image]

Comment: an interesting example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542801/solving-non-linear-equations-in-python